# PYTHONPATH missing from environment

Tags: python, bash

Please help me understand this. Here you can see that I have PYTHONPATH set (it's from my `.bashrc`)

```
jean@klippie:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH 
:/home/jean/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

But if I try to launch something in my local site-packages it is ignored:

```
jean@klippie:~$ gtimelog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jean/bin/gtimelog", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2671, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 654, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 552, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: gtimelog==0.5.0
```

Now if I manually export PYTHONPATH to exactly the value `echo` showed me above, it is NOT ignored:

```
jean@klippie:~$ export PYTHONPATH=:/home/jean/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages
jean@klippie:~$ gtimelog
# SUCCESS
```

Any clue what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably, you only set the shell variable `PYTHONPATH` in your `.bashrc`, but you don't export this variable to the environment.  Printing via `echo` only shows that the shell variable has the printed value.  Try

```
env | grep PYTHONPATH
```

to query if PYTHONPATH is really in the environment and make sure you really `export` it in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: That's it! What a newbie mistake to make. Curiously the skeleton bashrc (/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc) sets HISTCONTROL, PS1 and others without exporting. (Ubuntu 10.10)

Comment: @Jean: HISTCONTROL and PS1 are used by the shell itself -- they don't need to be exported to the environment.